# Why joinedload() is the better choice than selectinload() in many to one relationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, orm

I know how [`selectinload()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/orm_related_objects.html#selectin-load) and [`joinedload()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/orm_related_objects.html#joined-load) work. And I also know where to choose which. Based on the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html#what-kind-of-loading-to-use):

> **One to Many / Many to Many Collection** - The selectinload() is generally the best loading strategy to use. It emits an additional SELECT that uses as few tables as possible, leaving the original statement unaffected, and is most flexible for any kind of originating query. Its only major limitation is when using a table with composite primary keys on a backend that does not support “tuple IN”, which currently includes SQL Server and very old SQLite versions; all other included backends support it.
>
> **Many to One** - The joinedload() strategy is the most general purpose strategy. In special cases, the immediateload() strategy may also be useful, if there are a very small number of potential related values, as this strategy will fetch the object from the local Session without emitting any SQL if the related object is already present.

Also [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/orm_related_objects.html#joined-load):

> The joinedload() strategy is best suited towards loading related
> many-to-one objects, as this only requires that additional columns are
> added to a primary entity row that would be fetched in any case.

Yes, based on their behavior, `joinedload` is in better in "many-to-one" relation ship as opposed to "one-to-many" relationship. That's because the primary rows won't get multiplied in the former. But still the other table's rows are get multiplied. In many-to-one relationship, the result set won't grow vertically but horizontally.

What I'm trying to say is, I think even in many-to-one relationship, `selectinload()` would fetch less data.

Am I misunderstanding the concept? Are there other factors that makes "joinedload" a better choice than "selectinload" in many-to-one relationship?

Comment: Some databases may complain if an `IN ( … )` clause contains a very long list of values.

Comment: @GordThompson Yes. So in general case, Am I right to say that `selectinload()` is better even in many-to-one unless there are some limitations from the database?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to take measurements.  For extreme cases it might be easier to determine ie. Does every "many" have a unique "one" or Do all the "many" share the same "one"?

Overall though it probably depends on db server, size of tables, size of results, number of columns, etc.

IN GENERAL though I would think `joinedload` would be faster for average data sets, just because it is a single query, and the processing of the results is straightforward, just load them into the session sequentially, but ... you'd have to test it.